# BitmapDescriptor seems to change resolution of map marker image

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a custom map marker that I show on the map, but when I plot them the markers look blurry like the resolution was changed when looking at the original

this is the original

[image]

and I different colors of that

this is how they look when I plot them on the map

[image]

as you can see the edges looks all pixelated compared to the original one and it does not seem to matter what size image I use either.

Does using `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.blue)` really degrade the quality of the image?

how can I get them to look high quality like this in Google Now

[image]

are there some special image dimensions I need to use to get them to look better or something?

This is how I plot to the map

```
mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.blue)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here can the following

- You might be using the drawable which is good for mdpi or hdpi and you are using xhdpi screen.

Try adding drawables for all the drawables folder and then see the marker, i have faced the similar issue and this helped. Or use nodpi folder it will prevent images from getting scaled.

Comment: Yes you were right it was a folder problem, when I put that image in the xhdpi folder the image was nice but it was very small so it must have been scaling the image up which would then make sense with the resolution